# Widget that will flip between multiple textViews?

Tags: android, string, widget, textview

I have multiple strings that I want to show in a widget. The widget will need to have buttons to flip between the strings (wisdom words). My problem is that I can’t set up a button to change a textView to another. All I know is how to start an activity when you press a button and that is not what I want. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please use intent to get your activity -

```
Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,MyApp.Class);
startActivity(intent)
```